# What is the status of holographic sentience in the Federation?

Tags: star-trek

Over the course of several stories, and more specifically with the Doctor on Voyager, it's fair to say that Federation holograms, backed by appropriate computer cycles, can achieve self-awareness in a way that allows them to question their nature, expand their horizons, and even refuse to act in their "programmed" role.

Outside of the episodes and films, have any Star Trek authors tackled the monumental implications of a technology that can birth sentient life, but is used by its citizens for entertainment and utility?

Comment: The whole Moriarty arc in TNG springs to mind - the holodeck produces a character "worthy of being Data's opponent" and ends up grasping the concept of being a hologram on a space ship, and the fact that an outside world exists.

Comment: In Star Trek, not really. Sentient machines are really just treated as one of the perils of having advanced computers around. For a better discussion of the subject, you might want to look at the works of Iain. M. Banks where they discuss the problems of being able to create and destroy artificial lifeforms with little or no legal consequences.

Comment: Fridge logic: Starship computers have sufficient NLP that they _should_ be strong AIs, leading to the same sentience that the Voyager EMH enjoys. And yet, the ship's computer is never considered a person, even considering that ultimately it's the ship's computer generating things like the EMH and Moriarty.

Comment: @Richard Indeed, I'm a huge fan of Banks's Culture novels. He is sadly missed. :(

Comment: @BrianS I think the old TOS episode "The Ulitmate Computer" is the reason Star Trek computers aren't ever given that much autonomous direction.  Once bitten, twice shy.  Though the Enterprise did, peculiarily, 'give birth' in a TNG episode, complete with its own sentience.

Comment: More specific to this question, and just to clarify, are you asking *only* about holographic intelligence?  There's quite a bit of non-holographic intelligence floating around and being questioned about its relative nature in Star Trek, but fewer that are pure programs and fewer still that are holograms specifically.

Comment: Finally, while this isn't outside the episodes and films as you asked for, I should mention exactly how far the episodes themselves went in answering this question - The Doctor was brought to court for legal rights to his own holonovel "Photons Be Free", and while he didn't gain recognition as a living entity, he gained recognition as an Artist, with legal rights to his own published works. http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Author,_Author_(episode)

Comment: @Zibbobz. Yes to clarify, it's the issue of holographic sentience that I'm most interested in, especially because the more "real" a hologram is, the more pleasurable and fulfilling seems to be the interaction. I was going to admit subsequently that there is little distinction between a hologram's sentience and that of the computer that is generating it (Voyager's photonic life-forms aside), but now I'm wondering of that's actually true.

Comment: @NeilB - I've got every trek book known to man and I'm struggling to think of anything that suits the question. There's masses of holograms in the various novels but the question of developing sentient beings for pleasure/abuse is pretty dark stuff and not really the sort of topic that's addressed in the Trek universe.

Comment: @Richard I can't speak for the asker, but I think he's referring to how a more realistic representation of a virtual reality is more enjoyable, rather than pleasure of a more erm....'carnal' nature...

Comment: Torn if this is proper answer as your question asks about holographic sentience, but The Immortal Coil story line, followed up later in the Cold Equations Trilogy and later the Light fantastic has to do a lot with the nature of Artificial beings, specifically androids, and the plight of the Doctor is mentioned as relevant to their dilemmas but only cursorily. http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Immortal_Coil http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/The_Persistence_of_Memory http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/The_Light_Fantastic

Comment: @Richard Zibbobz is right, I meant "pleasurable" in the non-physical sense, as in, most crew members are more delighted the more realistic the holo-character is (excluding when it's a simulation of *them* of course!).

Comment: @NeilB - Well, Riker is especially "pleased" by Minuet and the crew of the Voyager enjoy the village they created. In both cases, their creations are operating at at least a semi-sentient level.

Comment: @Richard all true, I was just trying to steer the conversation away from that particular...area. :) It's not really what I had in mind.

Comment: @Richard: You have every *Trek* book known to man? Having read dozens of *Trek* books myself, I feel for you bro. What happened in your childhood to make you that much of a masochist?

Comment: Some of this is covered in Latent Image: http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Latent_Image_(episode)

Comment: @JamesSheridan - A few years ago I got access to an ebook library and helped myself to all 1309 Star Trek books.

Comment: @Richard: You know, I think my mother-in-law did the same thing, now that you mention it. I elected not to read any of them, in favour of other stuff. Might eventually get to them, but it would involve dealing with my mother-in-law, which is something even the guards at Guantanamo Bay consider cruel and unusual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the evidence of the stories we have in hand, I would have to say that the status of all forms of artificial sentience - holographic and electromechanical - in the Federation is, "We really don't want to have to think about it more than we have to." And by "we" I mean not merely the characters, but the writers! As evidence for which, I present:

- About half of Classic Trek (and every sentient computer Kirk talks into jumping off a ledge), but specifically, "The Ultimate Computer", wherein neither the writers nor the characters ever question whether it's OK to simply kill M5 (in fact, the writers structure the story to make the question pretty much impossible by making it an M5-or-everyone-else choice).
- "A Measure of a Man", the most in-depth treatment on the subject, I think, and the only one until VGR: "Author, Author" that really comes to any conclusion on the subject of strong AI.
- The Moriarty episodes, which I would point out end with an overt sense of "feel good" that gets creepy the minute you realize that Moriarty is now living a lie (and worse when you realize that he probably died without anyone thinking about it when *Enterprise* crashed at the end of *Generations*)
- The casual callousness with which *Voyager*'s crew dismiss the EMH whenever it suits them early in the series.
- The similarly callous treatment Vic Fontaine sometimes endures.

And, as a grey area:

- When Starfleet decided that EMH Mark I's bedside manner left something to be desired, the existing instances were repurposed as scut-work and mining systems (presumably using mobile holo-emitters or by setting up holo-grids within the mine?). So, on the one hand, Starfleet did not simply scrap them as defective computer programs. On the other hand, it's not clear that they were asked what they might want to do with their lives now that they were no longer EMHs. In short: they were treated enough like people to not simply be killed, but not enough like people to be given choices.

In the case of The Doctor and Vic, only the fact that the holographic entities demonstrated genuine usefulness did people start thinking of them as more than just 1s and 0s to be casually deactivated and reactivated when it was convenient. Sisko remains downright derisive of the amount of time his crew is spending helping Vic when the program deliberately throws him a curveball in "Badda-bing, Badda-bang", partially because he doesn't see Vic as anything other than another computer program, and partially because he disliked the entire lounge program as being set in a time and place where a black man would not really have been welcome! Even the fact that Vic Fontaine helped one of his junior officers (Nog) to get through the loss of a leg in battle doesn't make Vic a person to Sisko. Even when he finally participates, one never gets the sense he necessarily has changed his fundamental view on whether or not Vic is really a person -- an interesting and deliberate grey area for a black man concerned about historical racism!

Only in the case of the Voyager EMH, however, do we see even a possible future in which he seems to be treated by the Federation (not just by his crew-mates) as an emancipated person on a par with Data. I don't believe we learn exactly how that came to pass, and anyway, that timeline is erased, so there's no guarantee it will happen. On the other hand, "Author, Author" strongly suggests that The Doctor's work is influencing other instances of EMH Mark I.

Perhaps, if we had seen a series take place further in *Voyager*'s future, the writers would finally have found the courage to seriously tackle some of these issues more broadly. We'll probably never know.

Comment: I'm happy with this answer. It doesn't really take into accoun the EU novels but it's a good summary of the canon TV series'

Comment: You might want to look at the ending of  Author, Author for a glimpse at what I would regard as the **inevitable rise** of holographic sentient rights;  http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/717.htm

Comment: Not sure about timelines, but didn't Vic Fontaine's sentience emerge some time after his introduction, or at least the crew's discovery of his sentience. As such, Sisko's derision would make sense; VF was just a holographic lounge singer, the basis of Sisko's opinions, and then one day he somehow become more. Sisko could have refused to believe in the emergence of mind (just taking it as exceptionally crafty AI programming).

Comment: Yes and no. Vic was self-aware right from the beginning -- aware that he was a holographic program, aware that his "customers" were not holograms, and somewhat aware of 24th Century reality. Felix does seem to have wrought somewhat better than he knew (or perhaps better than he expected DS9's holosuite processors to manage), but the basic parameters of Vic's existence pretty much ensured at least some degree of sentience. One wonders if Vic is strictly legal, for those reasons alone...

Comment: @Richard - I can't really speak for most of the EU. There's only one set of EU stories I've read (Diane Duane's) that deals with the question at all, and it doesn't deal with it that differently than the series. If you like, I'd be willing to expand my answer with those details, but I don't think they add much.

Comment: @Richard - Also, reviewing the script at the link you pasted above, you're right -- I think I only saw the episode once, honestly, and had not recalled that coda. I suspect, but of course don't know for certain, that Mike Sussman (the writer of this and several other stories across the franchise) hoped to explore the idea further in the future. Sadly, neither he, nor the franchise, ever got the opportunity.

Comment: I've expanded the answer a bit to incorporate more from both "Doctor Bashir, I Presume" and "Author, Author" in terms of the implications for AI going forward.

Comment: In regards to Moriarty, he is in the trailers for Picard season 3, so not dead. I believe there was a EU story where Spock visits the planet that Kirk died on to retrieve the body, the ship was also being cleaned up, because a species present in the solar system was about to achieve spaceflight. This might explain how Moriarty is still alive.

Comment: @DafyddNZ Agreed. I write the answer above in 2014, when even _Discovery_ was merely a hoped for rumor, and we had no reason to believe these questions would ever again see the light of day in canon! I'm glad to see some of it getting addressed!

Answer (score 0):

"Star Trek: the Lower Decks" has an Exocomp who appears to be universally acknowledged to be at best a *real* jerk.

More generally, given that at least some institutions in the Federation may be democratic, the ability to create arbitrary numbers of bespoke voters at will could be problematic…. Then, of course, the question of whether one could legally simulate a genetically-enhanced human comes to mind.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  The question was whether there were any other works by *Star Trek* authors that dealt with the use of artificially-constructed sentiences for work or entertainment and the implications of that.  Merely noting the existence of another such in one of the shows doesn't really help.